# Angular 7 call phone

Tags: angular, href, call

I  want  implements  click  to  call  in  angular, but  when  i  click  my  button, this redirect  to  web.

Some  idea?

This  are my  component  and my  issue
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<a href="{{'tel:'+tel}}">{{tel}}</a>
```